# Alter statement Conflict with foreign key, but ID exisits in both table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, database-schema, database-administration

I've 2 tables, here I'm trying to insert a FK relationship. But, I'm getting errors when I try to alter the table to create an FK relationship please help...  I have club ID in both tables, I commented below, but I am not sure why I'm still getting the Constraint error.

What is causing the constraint error?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clubs](
[ClubID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  // ClubID is here
[Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](2047) NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Modified] [datetime] NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_Clubs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClubID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs](
[MemberClubID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemberID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ClubID] [int] NOT NULL,              //Club ID is here as well
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MemberClubs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MemberClubID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ON 
GO    INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ([MemberClubID], [MemberID], [ClubID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
GO    INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ([MemberClubID], [MemberID], [ClubID]) VALUES (2, 2, 1)
GO    INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ([MemberClubID], [MemberID], [ClubID]) VALUES (3, 3, 1)
GO    INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ([MemberClubID], [MemberID], [ClubID]) VALUES (4, 4, 1)
GO    INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] ([MemberClubID], [MemberID], [ClubID]) VALUES (5, 5, 1)
GO    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MemberClubs] OFF
GO


// *** The error is over here 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Clubs] FOREIGN KEY([ClubID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Clubs] ([ClubID])
GO

// $$$ The second FK constraint error is over here
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Clubs]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Members] FOREIGN KEY([MemberID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Members] ([MemberID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Members]
GO
```

The *error*:

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line ** * ** (Above)

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MemberClubs_Clubs". The conflict occurred in database "newDb", table "dbo.Clubs", column 'ClubID'.
```

Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line *$$$* (Above)

```
Constraint 'FK_MemberClubs_Clubs' does not exist.
```

Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line *$$$* (Above)

```
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: This looks like an intermediate table between Members and Clubs. The standard way to do this is to make a composite key of MemberID and ClubID instead of creating an identity column in this table for the primary key.

Comment: @SeanLange ok that changes the design and impacts some code. But I could possibly do that if it makes it simpler or cleaner. I 'm not sure I understand how a composite key is better that (associative table), i.e. I'm thinking composite key like C#. Unless there is something different in Sql

Comment: The point is that you already have the values needed for a primary key. It is using a simple natural key instead of just making up a magic number. It would be preferred from a design perspective imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add 5 rows into table `MemberClubs` referencing `Club.ClubId = 1`, before then adding a Foreign Key relationship to `Clubs`.

So in order to maintain referential integrity, you'll need to add a row with `ClubId = 1` into `Clubs` before adding / enabling the foreign key constraint:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Clubs] ON 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Clubs](ClubId, Name, Description, Created, Modified) 
       VALUES (1, 'Foo', 'Bar', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Clubs] OFF
```

Then the foreign key creation succeeds:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Clubs] FOREIGN KEY([ClubID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Clubs] ([ClubID])
GO
```

Comment: The odd thing is, if I run the `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Clubs]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberClubs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberClubs_Members] FOREIGN KEY([MemberID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Members] ([MemberID])
GO`  after the script errors out-- it works and creates the relationship!!

Answer (score 2):

If this is not an example and is what you're actually trying to accomplish, one thing I can see just by looking at your scripts is you're attempting to create a FK relationship with table using inconsistent data.

In order to create the constraint, consistent data must exist.  In your posted code, `Club`s has no data, so a constraint cannot be successfully created due to `MemberClubs` having "orphaned" data - e.g. `MemberClubs` is attempting to reference items in `Clubs` that does not exist.

Comment: Are you saying if I leave the couple rows of data out, this might work. I am trying it right now.